# Python crashes when using call (ntdll.dll)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4

I have a script that combines around 1000 files by using an external program. It does so by copying the first file to `combined.sym` and then combining the this file with all other files, one by one. Code is as follows:

```
# gets all .sym files
symfiles = []
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(myPath) if isfile(join(myPath, f))]
for f in onlyfiles:
    if '.sym' == splitext(f)[1]:
        symfiles.append(f)

# copies one initial combined file (point to start from)
combinedFileName = "combined.sym"
copyfile(myPath + symfiles[0], myPath + combinedFileName)
for sym in symfiles:
    print("processing " + str(sym))
    cmdString = combinedFileName + " "
    cmdString += sym
    cmdString += " -a " + combinedFileName
    finalCmdString = r'cmd.exe /C fuseFiles.bat "' + myPath + '" "' + cmdString + '"'
    call(finalCmdString)
print("done")
```

The batchfile I'm calling looks like this, but that is not the issue:

```
@set PATH=\path\to\executable\;%PATH%
@cd %1
@FusingProgram "%2"
```

Now, when I run this script, it runs for like 15 Minutes before it just stops and returns to the CMD.

```
processing onefile.sym
processing anotherfile.sym
processing evenmorefiles.sym
processing yougetit.sym

C:\Users\test\>
```

As you can see, it misses the "done" print, and it didn't process all files. The `combined.sym` is created and expanded by the other `.sym` files

When checking the Windows events, I can see, that it logs python as crashed and lists     `ntdll.dll` as faulty module(sorry for german log):

```
Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: python.exe, Version: 0.0.0.0, Zeitstempel: 0x53787196
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: ntdll.dll, Version: ****, Zeitstempel: 0x5b6db230
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x0002e2eb
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x6224
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d454e0ff20377c
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\pat\to\python\python.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Berichtskennung: 8b4254f0-c0d5-11e8-9a6f-901b0e5a6206
```

I've done some research and it seems like I'd have to resolve this by updating the ntdll.dll file, but my system is all up to date, so there is nothing I can do about that (except for downloading another version from some untrustworthy site, which I'm not gonna do)

All this being said, have you ever encountered a similar issue or is this just a stupid mistake I made?

Comment: Just tested it again and now it crashes after couple of seconds. Same behavior.

Comment: ntdll.dll has runtime-library and base system calls, so it's used extensively. An access violation (0xC0000005) in ntdll.dll doesn't tell us much. We need a stack trace or exception analysis (`!analyze -v`) from a dump file or from running the script with a x86 (32-bit) debugger attached to python.exe.

Comment: could you please be so kind and give me a hint on how I could do that? In terms of tools to use and stuff?